# What happens when few threads trying to call the same synchronized method?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

so I got this horses race and when a horse getting to the finishing line, I invoke an arrival method. Let's say I got 10 threads, one for each horse, and the first horse who arrives indeed invoking 'arrive':

```
public class FinishingLine {
    List arrivals;
    public FinishingLine() {
        arrivals = new ArrayList<Horse>();
    }

    public synchronized void arrive(Horse hourse) {
        arrivals.add(hourse);
    }
}
```

Ofc I set the arrive method to synchronized but I dont completely understand what could happen if it wasnt synchronized, the professor just said it wouldn't be safe.

Another thing that I would like to understand better is how it is decided which thread will after the first one has been finished? After the first thread finished 'arrive' and the method get unlocked, which thread will run next?

Comment: "*Another thing that I would like to understand better is how it is decided which thread will after the first one has been finished? After the first thread finished 'arrive' and the method get unlocked, which thread will run next?*" It's arbitrary. If you care, you're doing something wrong. Until you have a much better understanding of thread safety generally, it's really not productive for you to dig deeper in this particular direction. Desires for fairness or control over execution order almost always result from poor design.

Comment: Just to add to @DavidSchwartz's comment, if you are doing something as trivial as adding an element to a list, the arrival order is basically irrelevant. If two threads *happen* to try to add an element at the same time, one of them *must* go first; I dare say you will have a hard time actually reliably determining that A "should have been" before B. As such, fairness is not really useful; but it is available.

Comment: This is just a tiny home work program, ofc I wouldn't design it like that myself, I have forced to use it and has asked "Why it is't fair",etc.

Comment: It's not fair because implementing fairness is expensive and almost never needed. You code your threads to do the work that most needs to be done, so it doesn't matter what thread runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It is undefined what the behaviour would be, but you should assume that it is not what you would want it to do in any way that you can rely upon.

If two threads try to add at the same time, you might get both elements added (in either order), only one element added, or maybe even neither.

The pertinent quote from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.)

2) This is down to how the OS schedules the threads. There is no guarantee of "fairness" (execution in arrival order) for regular synchronized blocks, although there are certain classes ([Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) is one) which give you the choice of a fair execution order.

e.g. you can implement a fair execution order by using a Semaphore:

```
public class FinishingLine {
    List arrivals;
    final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);

    public FinishingLine() {
        arrivals = new ArrayList<Horse>();
    }

    public void arrive(Horse hourse) {
        semaphore.acquire();
        try {
          arrivals.add(hourse);
        } finally {
          semaphore.release();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it would be easier to do this with a [fair blocking queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), which handles the concurrent access for you:

```
public class FinishingLine {
  final BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(NUM_HORSES, true);

  public void arrive(Horse hourse) {
    queue.add(hourse);
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you suggest me to implement 'arrival' in 'fair' way? Meaning If horse 2 arrived before horse 3, but they are both waiting for the arrival method to get unlocked, horse 3 might be added to the list first despite horse 2 arriving first. I dont want that,

Comment: @DanielPr added example.

Comment: @DanielPr If you don't understand the basics of thread safety, you are a very long way away from caring at all about fairness or arrival order. I'd strongly urge you not to go in this direction because it's not particularly productive and it's not useful. Instead, keep learning about synchronization.